# Set proxy for all users and system accounts on Windows Server

Tags: windows, powershell, proxy, windows-server-2016

We are trying to deploy a ARM template for Azure. We want to set the proxy for all users and system accounts. But we are unable to do it.
When we use this powershell script, the current user has a proxy but not the system account. Any suggestions?

```
<#
.Synopsis
This function will set the proxy settings provided as input to the cmdlet.
.Description
This function will set the proxy server and (optinal) Automatic configuration script.
.Parameter ProxyServer
This parameter is set as the proxy for the system.
Data from. This parameter is Mandatory
.Example
Setting proxy information
Set-InternetProxy -proxy "proxy:7890"
.Example
Setting proxy information and (optinal) Automatic Configuration Script 
Set-InternetProxy -proxy "proxy:7890" -acs "http://proxy:7892"
#>

#[CmdletBinding()]
Param(        
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String[]]$Proxy,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [String[]]$acs      
)

Begin
{
    $regKey="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"        
}    
Process
{        
    Set-ItemProperty -path $regKey ProxyEnable -value 1
    Set-ItemProperty -path $regKey ProxyServer -value $proxy

    if($acs) 
    {            
        Set-ItemProperty -path $regKey AutoConfigURL -Value $acs          
    }

    #$obj = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::”HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections"
    #Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::”HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections" -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $obj.DefaultConnectionSettings
    #Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::”HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections" -Name SavedLegacySettings -Value $obj.SavedLegacySettings
    #$obj = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::”HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
    #Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::”HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name ProxyEnable -Value $obj.ProxyEnable
    #Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::”HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name Proxyserver -Value $obj.Proxyserver
}     
End
{
    Write-Output "Proxy is now enabled"
    Write-Output "Proxy Server : $proxy"

    if ($acs)
    {
        Write-Output "Automatic Configuration Script : $acs"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "Automatic Configuration Script : Not Defined"
    }
}
```

Comment: Silly question, is this a 100% cloud based deployment? Are you able to use group policies? If its not 100% cloud have you got access to DNS to deploy PAC files - assuming everyone needs the same proxy information?

Comment: No it is not (yet) possible. I don't know if it will be available in this company but for the time being not. So I only know that I have to set the proxy. As you can see it works for `Current User` but not for system wide.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

According to the script above, you've remmed out the keys you need.

You're setting the wrong key.  Try this one:

```
Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\DefaultConnectionSettings
```

On this key:

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18
```

And you should be golden!

Comment: I was trying to do this but the `Connections` piece is not there in `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18`. See the commented part in my script. I've got an error when I run that because `Connections` isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

## Encoded configuration method

The whole configuration is encoded by the system as binary values and stored in an array under the **DefaultConnectionSettings** registry value.

Advantage:

- You have only one registry value to handle

Drawback:

- You must create your configuration with an exsting user account in order to get the **DefaultConnectionSettings**
- You must apply it individually to each user

1.Set the **Connection Settings** like you desire in your current user session

2.Get the matching value of the **Connection Settings** from the **Currently Logged On User**

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections' -Name 'DefaultConnectionSettings'
```

3.Update the first line of this code with the former result to set the same settings on the **System Account**

```
#This is the new connection settings you want to apply
$DefaultConnectionSettings = [byte[]](70,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,119,101,98,112,114,111,120,121,46,109,121,100,111,109,97,105,110,46,99,111,109,47,112,114,111,120,121,46,112,97,99,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

#This is the key of the LOCAL SYSTEM account
$IESettingsKey = 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'

$IEConnectionsKey = Join-Path -Path $IESettingsKey -ChildPath 'Connections'

#If the Connection subkey does not exist, create the subkey
If(-not(Test-Path -Path $IEConnectionsKey)){
    New-Item -Path $IESettingsKey -Name 'Connections'
}

try{
    #If the DefaultConnectionSettings already exists, set it with the new value
    $Null = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $IEConnectionsKey -Name 'DefaultConnectionSettings'
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $IEConnectionsKey -Name 'DefaultConnectionSettings' -Value $DefaultConnectionSettings
}
catch{
    #If the DefaultConnectionSettings does not exist, create it with the new value
    New-ItemProperty -Path $IEConnectionsKey -Name 'DefaultConnectionSettings' -Value $DefaultConnectionSettings -PropertyType Binary
}
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation what this does?

Comment: Hi Ralf! You are right. I have added comments to the code.

Answer (score 1):

## Explicit configuration method

The configuration is a combination of several registry values.

### Advantage:

- The configuration is humanly readable.
- The configuration can be applied to all users at once.

### Drawback:

- There is no registry value to enable or disable the **Automatically detect settings** setting
- If you use PowerShell, you have to ensure that the parent registry keys exist and check if the matching values exist or not before you can set the data.
  For example, when you want to set the AutoConfig value, you must first create the Control Panel registry key (if it does not exist) or you will get an error.

### Configuration values:

#### Note

Values located under
`HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`
must also be set under
`HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`

- **Use automatic configuration script**

```
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL = URL
```

Example: `http://proxy.mydomain.com/proxy.pac`

- **Use a proxy server for your LAN**

```
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable = 0|1
```

- **Proxy address to use** and **Use the same proxy server for all protocols** checked

```
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer = URL:PortNumber
```

Example: `http://proxy.mydomain.com:80`

- **Use the same proxy server for all protocols** unchecked

```
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer = List of URL:PortNumber
```

Example: `http://proxy.mydomain.com:80;https://proxy.mydomain.com:443;ftp://ftp.mydomain.com:21`

- **Bypass proxy server for local addresses** and NOTHING in **Do not use proxy server for addresses beginning with**

```
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride = <LOCAL>
```

Example: `<LOCAL>`

- **Bypass proxy server for local addresses** and SOMETHING in **Do not use proxy server for addresses beginning with**

```
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride = FQDN list
```

Example: `Mydomain.com;AnotherDomain.com`

### Application scope:

- Apply the proxy configuration to all users

```
HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxySettingsPerUser = 0|1
```

- Prevent users from overriding Proxy Configuration

```
HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel\Proxy = 0|1
```